# Copy-paste files to folders that have matching names using R

Tags: r, directory, batch-processing, copy-paste

I am trying to copy files to various folders that have matching filenames.

Here's an extract of the filenames:

```
20201026_ABCD.txt
20201026_XYZ.txt
20201027_ABCD.txt
20201027_POR.txt
20201028_ABCD.txt
20201028_PQR.txt
```

I want to create folders that have just the date components from the files above. I have managed to get that far based on the code below:

```
setwd("C:/Projects/TEST")
        
library(stringr)
        
filenames<-list.files(path = "C:/Projects/TEST", pattern = NULL)
        
#create a variable that contains all the desired filenames
foldernames.unique<-unique(str_extract(filenames,"[0-9]{1,8}"))
    
#create folders based on this variable
foldernames.unique<-paste("dates/",foldernames.unique,sep='')
lapply(foldernames.unique,dir.create,recursive = TRUE)
```

Now, how do I copy `20201026_ABCD.txt and 20201026_XYZ.txt` to the folder `20201026`, so on and so forth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now you just need to use `file.rename` to move the files. First i'll change things a bit to capture the non-unique folder names so I don't have to recauclate them. How about this

```
srcfolder <- "C:/Projects/TEST"
filenames <- list.files(path = srcfolder, pattern = NULL)
        
#create a variable that contains the desired foldername for each file
foldernames <- file.path("dates", str_extract(filenames,"[0-9]{1,8}"))
foldernames.unique <- unique(foldernames)
    
#create folders based on unique values of variable
lapply(foldernames.unique, dir.create, recursive = TRUE)

# Now move files
file.rename(file.path(srcfolder, filenames), file.path(foldernames, filenames))
```

We just build the file names with `file.path` which is a bit more robust than `paste()`

Comment: Awesome, that worked like a charm. Can you please explain the logic behind file.rename? It never occurred to me! Thanks once again.

Comment: It's just two parameters, old name, new name. As long as you put the paths together, you can move a file to whatever existing folder you like. Renaming a file is basically the same thing as moving it.